How to list all threads of the host OS from within a Java VM?
Is there some API in the Java standard library with which from within a JVM some Java code can be executed that lists all OS threads of the host OS the JVM is running on?
In particular, I don't want to list all the Java threads of the JVM that executes my Java code, but a list of the OS threads of the host OS of which the host process running the JVM is just one of the OS threads. So I want a list of OS threads analoguously to what the Linux top command would show by running Java code.
At best have a way that from within Java the OS thread id can be queried that runs the JVM in which the Java code is executed to list all those OS threads. Would be needed for some load balancing I would like to implement for Java.
UPDATE:
In the meanwhile I found hyperic sigar which calls libraries written for Windows and Linux. Unhappily it crashes on me and seems to be discontinued.
Being on Windows I do load the Sigar Windows DLL. Calling "System.loadLibrary" works for me (crashed till I got it working):
static {
        System.loadLibrary("sigar-amd64-winnt");
}

But running code from the sigar.jar causes stack dumps:
public static void main(String[] args) throws SigarException {
    var sigar = new Sigar();
    var list = sigar.getCpuList();
    for(var cpu : list) {
        System.out.println(cpu);
    }
}

But then executing "sigar.getCpuList()" causes a crash:

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuListNative()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/Cpu;+0
j  org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getCpuList()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/Cpu;+1
j  org.objectscape.Scratch.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

It seems that the Windows dll does not work any more for newer JDKs.
Think there was a way to list all OS threads of the OS some JVM is running on which was added in a newer JDK. Just can't remember it and can find it any more searching the Internet ...

I think this looks like a XY Problem. Why do you think you need to do the load balancing yourself? Java is already optimized to do so within its own JVM. Also most of all techniques that Java supports are statically set, that is, they are parameters set either at the application level or the JVM level before the program itself runs.

Also ... what the OP is doing here is some kind of benchmarking activity.  In practice one does not calculate large Fibonacci numbers that way.  It has a simple closed form that doesn't benefit from multi-threading; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Generating_function.  And memoization is another trick to use.

More generally, load-balancing threads from within the JVM (e.g. by tweaking thread priorities) is a bad idea.  Better is to manage (throttle) the number of threads created by using a ExecutionService with a fixed pool size and letting the OS take care of thread scheduling.  (Or maybe use a fork-join pool if you are doing a divide and conquer computation like pure recursive Fibonacci ...)

@Stephen: Yes, absolutely right. What I have in mind is to evict a task to some other machine in the network when the machine currently executing the task is too much under load already, because load has changed in the meanwhile dynamically.

Post your solution as an Answer, not an edit to the Question.

And, you can accept your own Answer too, click on the big checkmark.

You wrote (in your question): Think there was a way to list all OS threads of the OS some JVM is running on which was added in a newer JDK. Perhaps you mean the Process API

@Abra: ProcessHandle.current() gives me the OS process that runs the JVM "where I am in". This can be seen from the data dislayed when executing ProcessHandle.current().info(). In the end operatingSystemMXBean.getCpuLoad gives me the value I was really looking for. But a good hint, thanks anyway.

Think I now found a way to do it by calling ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() to get a OperatingSystemMXBean, and casting to a OperatingSystemMXBean (same name, confusingly).
var operatingSystemMXBean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) 
ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean(); 
System.out.println(operatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad());

The CPU load percentage printed to the console is about within a certain range what Windows task manager is showing. So the value seems to be meaningful enough for my purposes.

getSystemCpuLoad is deprecated, with note advising the use of getCpuLoad.

I wonder if getSystemLoadAverage would help you.

Why did you ask for a list of all threads of the host OS when you actually wanted to know the CPU load?

@Holger: Because I didn't knew that there is an API call that gives me straight away the current CPU load of the JVM (out of possibly several other JVMs running on the same machine) and first thought I need to figure out myself which of all those running java.exe is the one running my application.

But what was the plan? Step 1 get a list of all threads of the system. Step 2 ????

Step 2: Find the process running "my" JVM so that I can obtain the CPU load of my JVM and not of some other JVMs on the same machine doing other things, run by other people. As already said, this is meanwhile not relevant any more as operatingSystemMXBean.getCpuLoad() gives my straight away the CPU load of "my" JVM.

ProcessBuilder lets you run shell script  from Java. See this Answer.
Foreign Functions supplants JNI as a way to call native code outside of the JVM. You can call into the host OS.

Oh, right. The new  Foreign Function API would allow to call the Windows API call for this myself. Guess for Linux it is only reading the current value from some system file. If ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() does the job, I will stick to it as the work would already be done then ;-). But thanks for the hint.
